# I expected to see value in the section of View Child Value as i created a directive which is PaDisplayValue, but failed

Tags: angular, directive

```
<div class="bg-info text-white m-2 p-2">
    View Child Value: <span PaDisplayValue> </span>
</div>

<div class="bg-info text-white m-2 p-2">
    Content Child Value: <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Please find the whole project in the following git repo:
https://github.com/codezj/example-directive-issue.git

Comment: How are you passing `<ng-content>` ?

Comment: `<div class="row m-2">
    
    <div class="col-4 p-2">
        <paProductForm>
        <span paDisplayValue></span>
      </paProductForm>
    </div>

    <div class="col-8 p-2 ">
     
        <paProductTable>
        </paProductTable>
    

    </div>
</div> `@O.MeeKoh,  I pass it in the template.html and template.html include the component which is display in question part, if you download my project in the git, you will understand it, please let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: `<div class="col-4 p-2">
        <paProductForm>
        <span paDisplayValue></span>
      </paProductForm>
    </div>`